# In House Print Resolution

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, resolution

What is the standard setting for low, med and high print resolution when exporting (under Compression menu) a PDF file from InDesign at an in-house studio?

Answer (score 1):

Any resolution would be *highly* dependent upon the capabilities of the print device(s).

- For *most* end use Inkjet printers 150dpi is as high as is necessary.
- Some higher-end inkjets, with a RIP, are capable of supporting 300dpi. As are laser or wax printers.

These are typically the only two numbers you need for printing resolution. *Anything* lower than 150dpi would be of lower quality. The lower the resolution, the lower the quality.